# Flask 302 error code when using flask.redirect

Tags: python, flask

I have this code https://github.com/italomaia/flask-empty/blob/master/src/0.8/main.py and I wrote at the end of the file:

```
def configure_before_request(app):
    @app.before_request
    def before_request():
        hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(app.config['PASSWORD'], rounds=8000, salt_size=10)
        if session.get('logged_in') != hash:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
def configure_views(app):
    @app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(app.config['PASSWORD'], rounds=8000, salt_size=10)
            if request.form['login'] == app.config['USERNAME'] and pbkdf2_sha256.verify(request.form['password'], hash):
                session['logged_in'] = hash
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                flash(u'Неверный логин или пароль')
        return render_template('login.html')

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        return 'index_page НАХ.'
```

If I run this code, I get 302 server error (`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`), but if I change this line `return redirect(url_for('login'))` by `return 'Hello!'` it works without errors! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 302 is not a server error.  302 Found is an HTTP status code.  Server errors are HTTP status codes that fall in the 5xx category.  But in actuality, in performing a redirect, A 302 Found with the Location of the redirect is what you want.  I don't know what (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) is, and I don't know the answer to your question.  But a 302 is a correct way to implement a temporary redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not a specialist on flask. But obviously you are using a signal before the request gets mapped to a handler to check for credentials and then redirect to a handler. But the redirect in turn will trigger another request to your app and invoke the same function again, sending you into an infinite redirect loop. 
(Error 302 is a specific http error for this situation)

My advice: Check for credentials on per handler function basis or make at least an exception to your before_request function that it doesn't get invoked when a request to **"login/"** occurs.

It *might* also be possible to directly invoke the function that handles **login/**

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```py
if session.get('logged_in') != hash:
```

by

```py
if session.get('logged_in') != hash and request.endpoint != 'login':
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15175965/2) to the question [Why i get 302 error on flask.redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175965/why-i-get-302-error-on-flask-redirect) by the OP [Nolik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035651/nolik) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>